# django throws 'function' object has no attribute 'objects', while picking data from models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm actually playing with manual signin forms and while I was trying to query data from database it threw me this error.....

views.py ----section

```
def signin(request):
        username = 'not logged in'
        notify = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = signinForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                signup_data = signup.objects.all()    #     focus here
                for data in signup_data:
                    name = data.user_name
                    passw = data.password
                    if name == username and passw == password:
                        post = form.save(commit=False)
                        post.save()
                        request.session['user_name'] = username
                        return redirect('/home')
                notify = "Incorrect User name or Password"
                return redirect("/home/signin")
        else:
            form = signupForm()
            signins=blog.objects.all()
            number=len(signins)
        return render_to_response('blogger/signin.html', {'form':form, 'signins': signins, 'number':number, 'notify': notify}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: obviously `signup` is not a model, its a function.

Comment: it's in my model also...... maybe i should try changing names

Comment: also, please use `PascalCase` for naming models(according to pep-8 style guide)

Comment: That's not how you should sign in users. Read [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests) of Django documentation. Don't reinvent the wheel.